# How to allow users to submit answers to a questionnaire app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a questionnaire app.
for now I've 3 models

1- `Exam -> has_many :questions`

2- `Question -> has_many :answers && belongs_to :exam`

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @questions = Question.all
  end

  def show
    exam = Exam.find(params[:exam_id])
    @question = exam.questions.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    exam = Exam.find(params[:exam_id])
    @question = exam.questions.build
    @question = Question.new
    @question.answers.build
  end

  def create
    exam = Exam.find(params[:exam_id])

    @question = exam.questions.create(question_params)

      if @question.save
        redirect_to @question.exam, notice: "Exam created!"
      else
        render :new
      end

  end

  def destroy
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @question.destroy
    redirect_to @question.exam
  end



  private
  def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:title,:timer,:exam_id,answers_attributes:[:title,:correct, :question_id], :sort => [])
  end

end
```

3- `Answer -> belongs_to :question`

I can add an exam, and add questions to the exam and add answers for each question. (through nested form)

So for now the admin is the only user who can add exams,questions,answers. I want make the exam visible to other users so the can take and exam and see the result.

I thought about making a 4th model for submission that belongs to Exam where users can see the questions with the options and chose the option that they want and submitting it. After the submit they get a page with the result if the pass the exam or not!

**BUT HOW TO DO IT?**

UPDATE!!!
The code above works fine!. I'm only searching for some way to make the exam visible or takable for the users

```
<%= form_for [@exam, @submission]  do |f| %>
      <% @questions.each do |question| %>
        <p><%= question.title %></p>
        <ul>
          <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
          <li>
            <%= @chosen_option = answer.title %>
            <%= f.fields_for :option do |o| %>
              <%= render 'option_fields', :f => o %>
            <% end %>
          </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
    <br>
    <br>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn  btn-primary " %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Please can you provide a more complete overview of your code? What are your models, **controllers and views**? Your question as it currently stands is too broad for a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: Just update the code!

Comment: The 4th model idea is quite good. You should do that :)

Comment: I tried it, but for some reasons it's not working :(

Comment: I can list the questions and the answers, but I didn't mange to make it in form so that it can be submitted

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why you have separate controllers for exams, questions, answers and possibly now submissions.  Wouldn't it be easier to have just an exams controller, user controller, and an admin controller, and under the exams controller for the "Create" action make sure that there is some sort of ```before_action``` ensuring that only a logged in administrator can create an exam?  I'm not trying to be nit picky, I really just want to understand the structure and your reasoning so I can familiarize myself with the issue.

Comment: @FaisalAl-Sudani _"I didn't mange to make it in form so that it can be submitted"_ – what have you tried so far to build that form? Could you show some code? (BTW, the controllers and views for your admin don't seem to be relevant to your question)

Comment: @tfantina Each Exam have many questions. Each question have a title, sort ( multichoice, number, yes no) and a timer. And each Question have max 4 answers, where answer have title and correct. and that works fine, I don't know if it's possible to do in just one controller

Comment: @Stefan don't think about the admin thing, lets say all users can take the exam :D

Comment: @Stefan updated with Submission controller

Comment: @FaisalAl-Sudani where do you build the form?

Comment: @Stefan in views/submissions/new

updated

Comment: You can't write multiline code in comments. Please edit your question instead. And you should probably reduce the question to your model structure and the form building. The other controllers are irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, so what's wrong with your form? Do you get any errors or unexpected output?

Comment: @FaisalAl-Sudani  makes sense, sorry, I wasn't thinking about that, I do think you did that the right way.  You now say that you are looking for a way to make the exam open to users (rather than admins)?  Is that the question?

Comment: @Stefan it submit a submission entry without taking any value from the answers. even if I use submission_params with answers_attributes: [:answer_id]. the radio button is acting as one button for all questions. and also get this Unpermitted parameter: answers

Comment: @tfantina for let's say make the exam open to all users

Comment: So you want something like ```User -> has_many :questions``` so that you could match the user to every question they answered.  (I'm assuming you have a user model and these aren't just anonymous questions).

Comment: @tfantina I've user model, but there is no relationship between user and questions. I'm searching for way to make a form where users/guests anyone to answering the questions and submit

Comment: @FaisalAl-Sudani if the below answer does not help can you put the project on github so I can fork it and mess around with it, I want to solve this but I think I really need to play with the code to figure out how to get what you want.

Comment: https://github.com/faisalalsudani/Questionnaire feel free :D

Comment: Cool, we can continue to discuss this there.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to work some more on your models.

I am assuming that every question has at least one correct answer (unless you are building a survey tool). If that is the case, you also need the notion of correct answer(s) to be encapsulated in the models.

**Case 1: Single correct answer per question**
Add a `correct_answer_id` to the question model.

**Case 2: Multiple correct answers per question**
If a question can have multiple correct answers you need to create a join table/model

```
# migration for model CorrectAnswer
create_table :correct_answers do |t|
 t.integer question_id
 t.integer answer_id #answer_id is the id of the answer selected by a user
end

# Also update the Question class
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
...
has_many :correct_answers
...
end
```

Note: I will recommend the second option even if you are planning on a single correct answer. This will allow your models to be flexible for any future requirements.

For creating submissions, you need to create a new Model called `Submission`. The fields of the submission model  with following fields

```
#migration for Submission model
create_table :submissions do |t|
 t.integer user_id
 t.integer exam_id
 t.integer question_id
 t.integer answer_id
end
```

You will need to create a corresponding Submissions controller which will allow you non-admin users to submit answers to an exam.

Do not forget to create appropriate index for the tables

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've a submission model that connect to user and exam. 
I also have correct:boolean attribute in the answer model.

The form that I use is  submitting only the exam_id and user_id and it's ignoring the answers

Comment: First, I do not think that the `correct` field should go in the `Answer` model. Nevertheless, if the answers are ignored, check the logs to see if when submitting the form, the server is receiving the parameters. If not , then something is wrong in your view. If the logs show that the server receives the answers, then something is wrong in the controller. In that case, check if you are permitting the answers as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

So, I already solved this problem by changing the questions model. 
I added a answers array to the question model

```
create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "answers", default: [], array: true
end
```

changed also something in the view of the form of submission

```
<% question.answers.each_with_index do |answer, index| %>
  <p><%= answer %><span>
     <%= radio_button_tag 'submission[answers][]',"#{answer}", id: "#{answer}", class: "form-control"%>
  </span></p>
<% end %>
```

The problem now is that I get the questions like this 
[radio_button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0TDX.png)
I can only select one radio button! So if I select answer_A from question 1 and then I select answer_B from question 2. Question 1 then will be deselect?